# Storing and using cookies without using selenium driver.add_cookie()?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, pickle

I'm working on a project where I'm pulling the url for all products on a given page and using scrapy to parse through all those individual urls for product data. The issue is, every time a url is loaded, a pop-up appears 3-5 seconds in prompting you to join there newsletter and the relevant html isn't loaded until after you exit out of this. Using Selenium would be extremely time-intensive so I wanted to ask if anyone knew of a better approach to this problem.

The code I tried is attached in an abbreviated version below. Essentially, I attempted to use driver.add_cookie() for each cookie in the parsing function on each product page, but this failed as the driver isn't recognized in this second function. When I added the driver to the parsing function it caused a new instance of chrome to be opened for every single product which is too much for my computer. I'd really appreciate any help/pointers on how to tackle this issue. Don't hesitate to ask for clarification!

```
`import scrapy
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pickle


class spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': { 'data/file/relevantData.jsonl': {'format': 'jsonlines', 'overwrite': True}}
        }


    def start_requests(self):
        driver_path = r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop'
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.headless = False
        driver = Chrome(executable_path=driver_path[1:],
                        options=options)
        driver.get('https://www.desiredurl.com/whatever')
       
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open('relevantSite_cookies.pkl','wb'))

        [Skipping some code...] 

            link_elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 'relevantXPATH')))
            for link_el in link_elements:
                url = link_el.get_attribute('href')
                print('\n\n'+url+'\n\n')
                yield scrapy.Request(url)
            


    def parse(self, response):
        cookies = pickle.load(open('kygunco_cookies.pkl','rb'))
        for cookie in cookies:
            driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        print('Parsing begins')

        [Code continues...]


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(spider)
process.start()`
```

Comment: post the url of the page you are trying to scrape

Answer (score 0):

> but this failed as the driver isn't recognized in this second
> function.

its obvious, the `driver` is defined in `start_requests` and its unknown in `parse` function. You should define it in class level and then access it as `self.driver`

```
class spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'

    driver = None

    custom_settings = {
        'FEEDS': { 'data/file/relevantData.jsonl': {'format': 'jsonlines', 'overwrite': True}}
        }


    def start_requests(self):
        driver_path = r'C:\Users\Me\Desktop'
        options = ChromeOptions()
        options.headless = False
        self.driver = Chrome(executable_path=driver_path[1:],
                        options=options)
        self.driver.get('https://www.desiredurl.com/whatever')
       
        pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open('relevantSite_cookies.pkl','wb'))

        [Skipping some code...] 


    def parse(self, response):
        cookies = pickle.load(open('kygunco_cookies.pkl','rb'))
        for cookie in cookies:
            self.driver.add_cookie(cookie)
        print('Parsing begins')
```